# How to speed up Google Sheets Apps Script

Tags: performance, google-sheets, google-apps-script, web-applications, http-post

Here's my Apps Script:

```
function doGet(e) {
   return ContentService.createTextOutput("POST request processed successfully!").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}

function doPost(e) {
   try {
Logger.log("Received POST request");

var sheetName = "Data Log"; // The name of the sheet to which data should be inserted.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
Logger.log("Sheet retrieved: " + sheetName);

var jsonData = e.postData.contents; // Json data received from the json payload in the post request.
Logger.log("JSON data received: " + jsonData);

var data = JSON.parse(jsonData); // Parse Json data into key-value pairs.
Logger.log("JSON data parsed successfully");

// Insert new rows before the existing data rows
var numRowsToInsert = data.length;
sheet.insertRowsBefore(2, numRowsToInsert); // Insertion begins from row 2 because row 1 consists of headers. 
Logger.log("Inserted " + numRowsToInsert + " rows into the sheet");

/////// Code for managing headers ///////// 

// Declare a list of headers of columns in the sheet.

// Instructions for declaration:
// 1. The headers in the list and the headers in the sheet must have the same order.
// 2. Any header in between other headers that should not be inserted with the data, must be added as an empty string to the list.
// 3. Headers in the sheet following the last header in the list will not be affected.

// Declaration
var headers = ["Date", "", "Energy Consumed (kWh)", "Meter ID", "Gateway Poll Result", "1st Register Value", "2nd Register Value"]; // Second element is empty string, because we don't want the script to insert data into the second column as it is a formula column. See point 2 in the instructions. 
Logger.log("Headers defined: " + headers.join(", "));

/////// Code End ///////

// Transform the key-value pairs into tabular data.
var orderedData = data.map(o => headers.map(h => o[h] || null));
Logger.log("Data transformed into tabular format");

// Add the tabular data to the sheet.
sheet.getRange(2, 1, orderedData.length, orderedData[0].length).setValues(orderedData);
Logger.log("Tabular data added to the sheet");

return ContentService.createTextOutput("JSON payload parsed to sheet rows successfully!").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
} catch (error) {
    Logger.log("Error occurred: " + error);
return ContentService.createTextOutput("An error occurred while processing the JSON 
payload: " + error).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  }
}
```

The script executes once a post request is made by a microcontroller running Arduino. The post request contains a JSON payload that is parsed to the target Google sheet by the Apps Script. Each JSON object in the payload is parsed into a row in the target sheet.

The target sheet contains the following headers.

```
Date
Panel
Energy Consumed (kWh)
Meter ID
Gateway Poll Result
1st Register Value
2nd Register Value
Human Date-Time
```

The columns "Panel" and "Human Date-Time" are populated by an array formula referencing from another sheet within the same spreadsheet. The other columns are populated from the JSON parsing in the script.

Below is a typical JSON payload sent with the post request.

```json
[
    {
        "Date": "**********",
        "Energy Consumed (kWh)": "**********",
        "Meter ID": "*",
        "Gateway Poll Result": "*",
        "1st Register Value": "*****",
        "2nd Register Value": "*****"
    },
    {
        "Date": "**********",
        "Energy Consumed (kWh)": "**********",
        "Meter ID": "*",
        "Gateway Poll Result": "*",
        "1st Register Value": "*****",
        "2nd Register Value": "*****"
    },
    {
        "Date": "**********",
        "Energy Consumed (kWh)": "**********",
        "Meter ID": "*",
        "Gateway Poll Result": "*",
        "1st Register Value": "*****",
        "2nd Register Value": "*****"
    },
    {
        "Date": "**********",
        "Energy Consumed (kWh)": "**********",
        "Meter ID": "*",
        "Gateway Poll Result": "*",
        "1st Register Value": "*****",
        "2nd Register Value": "*****"
    },
    {
        "Date": "**********",
        "Energy Consumed (kWh)": "**********",
        "Meter ID": "*",
        "Gateway Poll Result": "*",
        "1st Register Value": "*****",
        "2nd Register Value": "*****"
    },
    {
        "Date": "**********",
        "Energy Consumed (kWh)": "**********",
        "Meter ID": "*",
        "Gateway Poll Result": "*",
        "1st Register Value": "*****",
        "2nd Register Value": "*****"
    },
    {
        "Date": "**********",
        "Energy Consumed (kWh)": "**********",
        "Meter ID": "*",
        "Gateway Poll Result": "*",
        "1st Register Value": "*****",
        "2nd Register Value": "*****"
    },
    {
        "Date": "**********",
        "Energy Consumed (kWh)": "**********",
        "Meter ID": "*",
        "Gateway Poll Result": "*",
        "1st Register Value": "*****",
        "2nd Register Value": "*****"
    },
    {
        "Date": "**********",
        "Energy Consumed (kWh)": "**********",
        "Meter ID": "*",
        "Gateway Poll Result": "*",
        "1st Register Value": "*****",
        "2nd Register Value": "*****"
    },
    {
        "Date": "**********",
        "Energy Consumed (kWh)": "**********",
        "Meter ID": "*",
        "Gateway Poll Result": "*",
        "1st Register Value": "*****",
        "2nd Register Value": "*****"
    },
    {
        "Date": "**********",
        "Energy Consumed (kWh)": "**********",
        "Meter ID": "*",
        "Gateway Poll Result": "*",
        "1st Register Value": "*****",
        "2nd Register Value": "*****"
    },
    {
        "Date": "**********",
        "Energy Consumed (kWh)": "**********",
        "Meter ID": "*",
        "Gateway Poll Result": "*",
        "1st Register Value": "*****",
        "2nd Register Value": "*****"
    },
    {
        "Date": "**********",
        "Energy Consumed (kWh)": "**********",
        "Meter ID": "*",
        "Gateway Poll Result": "*",
        "1st Register Value": "*****",
        "2nd Register Value": "*****"
    }
]
```

Do note, the masked values in the payload can either be integers or decimals. There are no double quotes inclosing the values in a real payload.

The script sometimes completes it's execution within 10 seconds which is fine but some other times can take more than 200 seconds to complete, which too slow for my use case. How can I make the script run faster? Will replacing the apps-script API calls made in the script with something else make the script run faster? The json data I send through post request can range in size anywhere between 1-2 KB.

Comment: First thing to do is to use `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` to figure out the part which is slower.

Comment: Perhaps the slow performance isn't caused by the code but the spreadsheet? See [these spreadsheet optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339?msgid=102278707).